# PHP: script executing twice

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I have a php script which processes XML file uploaded by user . When file is big (like 50MB) it can take several minutes. On small files it works how it's expected. But I faced with one problem with large ones.

So, my file looks like:

```
if(file_exist($filename)) {
    return array(false, "File with this name already exist");
} else {
    /*
    Processing of file
    */ 
    return array(true, "")
}
```

When user upload file with javascript uploader, I make ajax request to this script. And the thing is that for large file it execute twice. For the first time it go to the "processing" section, at the second time it returns error that file with this name already exist (which is true, actually).

I add logging function in the beginning of the script

```
$logger = Zend_Registry::get('logger');
$logger->log('assign file function called', 7);
```

and I see that script has been called twice.

But in Firebug I see only 1 ajax request to the script. In Apache access.log I see only one request. Apache error.log is empty.

Any idea what it can be? Probably any configuration for long-time-executed scripts?

---

UPD Javascript for calling script

```
  $("#save_file_btn").click(function(){

        var filename    =   $("input#selected_file").val();
        if(!filename.length) {
            customAlert("Choose file at first");
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/otms/publisher/assign-file-to-publisher',
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                $("#add_form").html('<div class="loader"></div>');
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {filename: filename},
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.success) {
                    //Process added ONIX file
                    processOnixFile(data.fileId, function(){
                        getFileList();
                        $("#add_form").html('<div class="text-center">File has been successfully uploaded</div>');
                        setTimeout('$("#add_file_modal").modal("hide")', 2500);
                    });
                } else {
                    var output = '';
                    $.each(data.error, function(index,value){
                        output += '<div class="bold">'+value.title+'</div>';
                        output += '<ul>';
                        $.each(value.errorList, function(i, errorMsg){
                            output += '<li>'+errorMsg+'</li>';
                        });
                        output += '</ul>';
                    });

                    $("#add_form").html('<div class="red">'+output+'</div>');

                }
            }

        });

    });
```

I checked and this is the only place were any request is made to script 'assign-file-to-publisher' (where I have problem).

---

UPD 2.

What I found out is that script called twice only in Firefox browser. In Safari request doesn't return anything. In Chrome it returns the following status:

```
(failed) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I still do not see any error messages in my application logs or apache logs.
As I mentioned script works with big file and it can take up to several minutes to process it.

In my configuration:

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

while Chrome return error on 1:40 time.

Comment: There's no configuration that would make it execute a script twice. It must be something in your code that's doing it.

Comment: You should share your Javascript code, you know that the issue occurs in that area.

Comment: @scrowler Why do you think it's in the Javascript? Wouldn't Firebug show multiple AJAX calls in that case?

Comment: Since the Apache log shows only one request, the duplication has to be happening in the PHP code.

Comment: @scrowler I don't think, that duplication happens in javascript. But I can add javascript if you want :)

Comment: Is it a single PHP file? Or if you `include` your PHP file, try to use `include_once`. BTW you can try to run `die();` function in the end of your PHP file: bad solution for production but can helps you with debugging. You can call `var_dump(debug_backtrace())` or something like this in the end of your program.

Comment: @doubleui I don't use include or include_once since I use Zend Framework and all this happens automatically. The thing is that script is not executed to the end. And while it works on quite long operation (loadXML) second requests starts - at least it happens with Firefox browser. PS I added some additional details to my post.

Comment: Try [this example](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/w3c_tutorial/comm_tutorial/upload_ajax.htm) with header request and file.files[0]. And set ajax timeout  (not only PHP) to the bigger value.

Comment: Looks like a wrong solution but you can check that you bind click twice (if you call js twice or you have second #save_file_btn button). And append console.log('clicked') in the first line on call function and another console.log on beforeSend function.

Comment: And file_exists [has a cache state](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php). So write your file with fwrite with a+ to check if your small files writes twice too.